# how to download image / files from ftp server via url in android?

Tags: java, android, download

```
   private String ftpUrl = "ftp://%s:%s@%s/%s;";
   private static String host = "www.krishnas.com.np";
   private static String user = "tryagn@krishnas.com.np";
   private static String pass = "technology_krixnas";
   private static String filePath = "112.jpg";

   private static String savePath = 
   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + 
   Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM +"/abe.jpg";
```

My doInBackground() in asynctask is:

```
   protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
    int count;
    try {

    ftpUrl = String.format(ftpUrl, user, pass, host, filePath);


        //System.out.println("URL: " + ftpUrl)
                Log.d("-----------", ""+ftpUrl);

   //            try {
            //URL url = new URL(ftpUrl);
            //URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
     //                InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();

        URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();
        // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
        int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

        // Output stream
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(savePath);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
            i=(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile);
            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

   //                i = (int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile);

            // writing data to file
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        // flushing output
        output.flush();

        // c
        // losing streams
        output.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
    }
```

I want to download a file/image from my FTP server, it shows image in link but does not download in internal storage. I am learning ftp server downloader not the http request!! Don't know where it goes wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You are using external storage to store file `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

So if you want to store it in **internal storage**,
You can use `getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()`:

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
```

For more Information refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) link: